# Finding photos taken in a precise geotagged location?

Tags: google-photos

I have uploaded a number of photos with GPS data. I'm trying to find a few taken in NY Penn Station but my searches for even "new york city" or "new york, new york" aren't recalling all of the photos taken in that area. Is there a way to search by map? Or how else can I find these photos?

Comment: You mean that you have your photos uploaded to your Google Drive and you need to make an internal search based on the Geographical metadata that you had added in your photos ?

Comment: @VasilisKosmas Yes, however possible

Answer (score 1):

If you just click into the "Search" box in [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com), you'll get several different groupings of photos. One of the groupings is "Places".

Google groups these by using a combination of photo metadata and machine learning algorithms to recognize places.

I find, though, that Google's definition of a "place" can be...odd. For one thing, it can be awfully broad when defining an area. I also have one or two where if I click the photo for a grouping Google comes back with no search results. Anyway, I would look in there first to see if Google has defined the place for those photos as something you're not expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear, but "search by map" does ring a few bells. Check the google geolocation API. It's a powerful tool that does a lot of the work for you.

You can search by "Penn Station New York" turn that into a lat/long and cross it with your data in the images you uploaded.

This is just an idea for a tool you can use, I'd need more clarification for more specific information.

Comment: [This API?](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) Is there no app that does this already? I also updated the details, if that helps. The question is really how to find my photos on a map as I can't appear to search that way within Google Photos itself

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant geocoding seen [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). If you have location info for the photos you uploaded, you can display them on a map or display the photos within a given radius from your search terms